# SED - Add string to the end of nginx config block

Tags: unix, sed

The */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* file looks by default like this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I want to add something to the end of the http{} block, for example:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

So that it becomes:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

It is important that it is not depending on any of the existing content, it should just take the closing bracket as the reference point.

I do currently have this code:

```
sed -i '/^http {/a\    include \/etc\/nginx\/sites\-enabled\/\*\.conf\;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Unfortunately, that is inserting it at the start of the block, not the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you GNU sed):

```
sed '/^http {/,/^}/!b;/^}/i\new content' file
```

Use a range to focus on the `http` section and *insert* the new content before the closing `}`.

Can also be written:

```
sed -e '/^http {/,/^}/{/^}/i\new content' -e '}' file
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! :)